# Build .csproj with MSBuild without project reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, csproj

When writing an MSBuild file from scratch, is it possible to build .csproj files directly without a reference to the solution they're a member of?  Introductory guides like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx) often explain how to compile individual .cs files or build a .csproj directly from the command line.

For example, command line MSBuild without a .sln reference:

```
msbuild helloworld.csproj /t:Build /verbosity:detailed
```

Or a .csproj given a .sln:

```
<MSBuild
  Projects="mysolution.sln"
  Targets="My_Project_File"
  Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform)"
  ContinueOnError="false" />
```

I haven't found any references mentioning building the .csproj within an MSBuild file without a .sln.  Is there a way and I'm just missing something?

Comment: Have you just tried `<MSBuild Projects="my_project.csproj" Targets="Build" />` ?

Comment: Does your individual project reference any other projects.."by project" ?

Comment: @stijn that worked.  Thank you very much.  You should add it as an answer, too.

Comment: 1. Re: "without a reference to the solution they're a member of". In case you didn't know, a project is an unknowing member of zero or more solutions (which could be in any place in the file system). 2. If you're interested, MSBuild can build a Visual Studio solution file by converting it on the fly to a temporary MSBuild project file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing wrong whatsoever with building csproj files without a solution:

```
<MSBuild Projects="my_project.csproj" Targets="Build" />
```

moreover, when you build a solution with Visual Studio what it actually does internally is convert the solution file to an msbuild script that contains a line like the above to build the projects.